# Display string to CircularImageView in Android

Tags: android, string, image

I have Strings like this

```
"android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@f79d418"
"android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4aa0d24"
"android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@1a7eac9"
"android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@f96242a"
```

I want to show these images into com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
I try to set them like this

```
Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(arrayListUserData.get(position).image)
                .into(holder.userProfileImage);
```

But this work if the image is with URL

Comment: These `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@f79d418` are not valid paths, they are the objects in memory. You can directly load a bitmap.

Comment: Then how to save it. I save it like this edtImage.getDrawable().toString()